# AngularJS treats POST response as string array instead of just string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, post

I am making a POST request:

```
var offers = $resource('/api/offers/:id', { 
    id: '@id' 
}

offers.save({}, { name: $scope.newOfferName }, function (offerId) {
    $location.path('/offers/' + offerId);
});
```

I expect offerId to be a string "key", but instead I get an array [0] "k", [1] "e", [2] "y".

On the backend I use Nancy and I return the response using:

```
Post["/"] = _ =>
{
    return Response.AsText("key");
};
```

The response Header say Content-Type:text/plain and in Chrome preview (Network tab) I can see "key".

When I return an object as JSON it's working fine, but I don't want to create fake class (having a string field) just to pass a string to the client.

I assume Nancy is fine here. What is happening with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular has a default transform that tries to parse incoming data as json.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L94

You could remove that transform from the transformers array in $http completely, or replace it with one that checks the content-type before trying to transform the data.

Comment: Good to know that '#L94' following Github link brings you to 94th line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a *class* for that. You can use an anonymous type:

```
Post["/"] = _ =>
{
    return Response.AsJson(new { offerId = "key" });
};
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I will do, but the answer by @Zerot explains why is it like that, so I mark it as an answer.